# QmlApplicationViewer::setFixedSize does not reflect the same size in xwininfo

Tags: c++, qt, window, x11, qml

How can one control the size of QmlApplicationViewer ? I am using QmlApplicationViewer as a launcher for QML application, and in QML, I set size as...

```
QmlApplicationViewer viewer;
viewer.setFixedSize(1280,720);
```

but on X11 side, if i query size. it does not match the size requested in Cpp side.

```
xwininfo -root -children | grep application_name
```

can anyone please tell, how can I control the size from with in Qt/QML code ?

Thanks in advance for any tip.

Comment: xwininfo probably includes window decoration? Then you need to take QWidget::frameGeometry into account. (frameGeometry().height() - geometry().height() should give you the height of the frame and titlebar).

Comment: no window manager or window decoration is active on my configuration, it minimal X running on arm with cross compiled Qt... results are same over 4.8 as well as on Qt5 :( ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What one *could* do, if one can't get WM to play nice/or has no window manager, is to set 
this flag on your top-level window right after the constructor and 
before the setFixedSize():

viewer.setWindowFlags(viewer.windowFlags() | Qt::X11BypassWindowManagerHint);

Please note the documentation for this flag:

"Bypass the window manager completely. This results in a borderless 
window that is not managed at all (i.e., no keyboard input unless you 
call QWidget::activateWindow() manually)."